# Google Docs: Add a word to spell check?

Tags: google-drive

I'm editing a document using Google Docs.

I would like to add several words to the Spell Checker dictionary (e.g. 'Lasiewski' ;). This feature used to exist. However, I don't see a way how to do this, and read that this feature [may have been removed](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=16d199dd193737c0&hl=en).

Is it possible to add words to the spell checker dictionary in Google Docs?

Can anyone provide any official links regarding this change?

**Update**:

I realize that I can use the spell checker in my browser. However in Google Docs, if I right click I am presented with the Spell Check menu from Google, not from my browser. Is there a magic key combination which allows me to use my browser's spell check?

Even with the browser's spell check feature, it would be great to be able to use gdoc's spell-checker as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs added this feature around August 2010. The Google Docs blog post at [Table resizing and other niceties in documents](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/08/table-resizing-and-other-niceties-in.html) says:

> **Add words to your dictionary**
>
> You can add words to the spellchecking dictionary by right-clicking on
>   any word that’s marked as misspelled and selecting Add to dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Most web browsers have spell-check built in now. For example, I'm writing this in Chrome for Mac and find that missspelled wordes get highlighted.

In order to add words to your broswer's spell-checker, you should be able to Right Click (Ctrl-Click, on a Mac) and select "Add to Dictionary." This works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, for Mac and PC.

Good luck!

Comment: In Google Docs, when I right click I get a Spell Check menu from Google, not from my browser. I suppose I need to find the right key combination to get the Firefox menu instead of the Google menu.

Comment: Lol @ "missspelled wordes"